# Command not found: [html2xhtml] exception happens when using Html2Xhtml library

Tags: html, xhtml

I have added **`HTML2XHTML`** as a nuget package to my project.

However I get "command not found" exception when I try to use

```
using Corsis.Xhtml;

//input is an html string

var xhtml = Html2Xhtml.RunAsFilter(stdin => stdin.Write(input)).ReadToEnd();
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not on the subject but this is related and may solve your problem.

Try this please :

- install SgmlReader from nuget
- in case you have a string variable like below you will have to convert it into a TextReader object.

Now we are going to use the package installed.

```
static XmlDocument HTMLTEST()
        {
            string html = "<table frame=all><tgroup></tgroup></table>";
            TextReader reader = new StringReader(html);

            Sgml.SgmlReader sgmlReader = new Sgml.SgmlReader();
            sgmlReader.DocType = "HTML";
            sgmlReader.WhitespaceHandling = System.Xml.WhitespaceHandling.All;
            sgmlReader.InputStream = reader;

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;  //false if you dont want whitespace
            doc.XmlResolver = null;

            doc.Load(sgmlReader);

            return doc;
        }
```

Input is string html format, and the return will be doc XmlDocument format. Your frame=all from html will become frame="all".

I can do whatever you like with the proper formatted XmlDocument doc, make it Xhtml if that's whant you wanted.

Comment: Sgml doesn't exist in current contex.I want to use it in .netcore3.1